# Async function returning Task(Of String) or String?

Tags: .net, vb.net, task-parallel-library, async-await

I'm learning [TAP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), and I'm wondering what feature of .NET allows the `result` in this method to be implicitly cast into or interpreted as a `Task(Of String)`:

```
Public Async Function CheckHostInstructionAsync() As Task(Of String)
    Dim result As String
    result = Await pipeReader.ReadLineAsync() 'pipeReader is a System.IO.StreamReader
    If (result.Equals("exit", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) Then terminate = True
    Return result
End Function
```

First, if `Await pipeReader.ReadLineAsync()` "returns" a `Task(Of String)`, why can I assign it to `result`, which is declared as a String?

Second, why can I say `Return result` though the return type is `Task(Of String)`.

Comment: @I3arnon -- I deleted your VB.NET tag.  My example is in VB.NET but my question applies equally to C# (or any other CLR language).

Comment: It doesn't matter. The tag doesn't limit exposure, it expands it. Most .Net question are language-agnostic, but they are still tagged  with the language they are in.

Comment: @I3arnon -- Gotcha.  I added it back.  Why does SO limit it to 5 tags max then?

Comment: That's a question for meta, but 5 is probably enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The feature is TAP itself (Task-based Asynchronous Pattern) or `async-await` as it's mostly called. The `async` keyword tells the compiler to generate a state machine and so you are able to use `await`. It also generates a `Task` (with the result value, if there is one) or any exception that may arise while the method is running.

In your case `pipeReader.ReadLineAsync()` returns a `Task(Of String)` and not simply `String`. `Await` is what enables you to "extract" the actual result out of that task when it's completed.

And when you return `result` yourself, the compiler knows to generate a `Task(Of String)` that when awaited results in a `String` (or an exception, if there was one)

Answer (score 5):

The key is in the [Async/Await](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) keywords.

`Async` tells the compiler that you're going to pretend you're returning a `string`, and it needs to deal with the complexity around the fact that you're actually returning a Task that will eventually yield a string.

`Await` can only be used in an `Async` method, and it tells the compiler that the next expression is going to return a `Task` that produces something, and the compiler needs to address the complexity around pretending that the rest of the code after this point is given that thing that the task will return (a `String` in this case).

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, not the `Await pipeReader.ReadLineAsync()` returns `Task<string>` but the `pipeReader.ReadLineAsync()` method itself. Having it `await`ed, you get the result of execution.

Secondly, returning the string from the method that is supposed to return `Task<string>` is done thanks to `async` decoration, that indicates the compiler to make this conversion for you.